# Effitiently sampling the error (noise) distribution in ring-LWE

Tags: lattice-crypto, ring-lwe

In [LPR12, page 4](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/230.pdf) is described a ring-LWE encryption in which we are working in a ring $R = \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n + 1)$ for a $n$ a power of 2. The public key is of the form $(a, b= a\cdot s + e)$ where $s$ is a secret key and $e$ a "small" element sampled form an error distribution. This is then generalized to other cyclotomic polynomials in [LPR13](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/293.pdf).

I am trying to understand how to (efficiently) implement a sampler for e. As it is described, the distribution for $e$ is a discrete (or discretized) Gaussian but in a bit scaled and screwed space. Probably the easiest way to see it is as in [CIV16, page 3](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/240.pdf) where they describe it by a linear transformation of a gauss sample. But implementing it in this way as a matrix multiplication seems inefficient. On the other hand, in papers like [RVMCV14](https://www.esat.kuleuven.be/cosic/publications/article-2444.pdf) it seems to me that there is no mentioning of any transformation.

I am asking what implementation would be preferred here? Actually I would be more than satisfied with an answer for when $R = \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n + 1)$ and $n$ is a power of 2.

Comment: When $n$ is a power of two, each coefficient of the polynomial error term is an independent (rounded/discrete) Gaussian. This is because the linear transform between the coefficient vector and the “canonical embedding” is a (scaled) orthogonal transform.

Comment: In the Newhope paper (https://www.usenix.org/conference/usenixsecurity16/technical-sessions/presentation/alkim) is described how discrete Gaussian can be replaced by a  binomial distribution.